# How to send an email from PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to sent email on DB field changes...
Can anyone please let me know how can I do it in PHPmyAdmin?

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin is just a web administration frontend for MySQL. You could probably write a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-views.html) and register it with a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) which will send the notification of a row change.

In my opinion this should be done in your application logic rather than the database.

Also see [How to send email from MySQL 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1)

Comment: i am working on web based application in which if you user put request... and and processed but user also have option of putting the new request if UI is not running than mail is not send do i want to handle it in Database.....so that is a required field changes than mail should be sent.........Can you please provide a Small example