# MySQL Auto-incremented ID number sent to User as registration number

Tags: mysql, forms, email

The question is in bold. Everything else is for context.

1. User submits form data, which is inserted into a MySQL db. The MySQL db generates an auto-incremented "id".
2. **"id" is then (auto) pulled out of the db and is emailed to User** via a "Success" email.

Possible? How?
Thanks,
Leo Jerome

Comment: Yes. What language is this for?

Comment: Did you try something? I think that's a very straight question and you can find many articles on the web explaining how to read the last inserted ID from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Its definatly possible. Depends what language your most familiar with but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1)
is one way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using php, use mysql_insert_id() to get the id of the last inserted record. It returns an int.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you are able to receive the last id inserted by using `mysql_insert_id()` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)) and further `mail()`