# Daily Alert for No New Database Records

Tags: mysql, alert

How would one set up an email alert to be sent, if there are no new records inserted into a MySQL database by a certain time?

I have a simple table consisting of an id and a datetime field. Ideally I would like to receive an email alert if *no* records are inserted to the database by 10:00am every day. Is this at all feasible?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email from MySQL 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1)

Comment: @Click - there's more to the this question than just sending emails.  So it's not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep this entirely within the database, you need to create an EVENT which runs once a day (say 10:00:01).  [Find out more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).

This event would execute a query to check whether any records have been received since the last time you checked.   Something like [the query proposed by Teez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9412323/146325) would suffice.

However, you might want to add a little more smarts into this , to allow for outages.  If the database is down at 10.00.01 and the query ends up running at 10:05 you wouldn't want a message received at 10:04 to corrupt the result (or would you? depends on the business rules - perhaps that record should have been inserted at 09:59 but the database was down...)

Anyway, if the query count is zero then you want to send an alert.  There is a project named MySQL Messages which provides APIs to do this.  [Check it out](http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=2).

As there are a couple of calls here you'll need to bookend the statements with `BEGIN` and `END`.

If you do go down this route, make sure the event scheduler is switched on.  [Find out more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

Comment: Thank you! This is a very thorough reply which basically provides me with all the pieces I need to put together.

Answer (score 1):

You seed to set up a `cron job` by sql query with `datetime` field for gettng records of 1 day interval.

It no record (`count=0`) then you need to execute code for sending mail alert.

Query wil be like below:

```
SELECT  count(id)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   datetime_field_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Please do required changes.

Comment: Cron or the Windows equivalent which is Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cron job

For ex

```
 0 10 * * * Your job over here
```

0 -  minute

10 - hour

so Every day 10 AM cron will execute you job.

For More reference go through this site http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference