# How to send email after backup is completed on windows using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i am really new to MYSQL . i have  learnt how to backup the database .now i want to know how to add the email id when the backup was taken.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show some research effort when posting a question. You should prove you have either googled the topic of the question, or tried doing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, as far as I know. MySQL doensn't have any function to send e-mails, you should use another language. Also, [searching on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20sending%20email) or googling (I came there through Google) would have lead you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1), which discusses nearly the same problem.