# How to automate mySQL .csv files to be sent to an email?

Tags: mysql, email, automation, database-backups

Our team is working on a database at my website (`.php`). We are inserting values everyday. How can I automate that database backup, i.e. i want it to be sent to my gmail everyday at 12:00? Preferably, i'd like to have a .csv file.

I know one way to do that...I could set up `Java` using `Selenium`...but I wanted to use a `stored procedure` in `mySQL` that would do that. I have experience in `PL/SQL`, but never used  mySQL counterpart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1