# Send email on database insert

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a mysql table with 3 columns:

- email_address
- email_message
- message_status

I need to create an application that keeps track of this table and whenever a message is inserted into the table with a message status of `0`, the application should send the email message and update the message status to `1`.

Comment: People appreciate it if you give more information, especially what you have already tried.  And welcome, by the way!

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. What is the element you're struggling with? Polling the table? Sending the e-mail? Updating the table?

Comment: Help with what?  What is your question?  StackOverflow is a site for questions and answers.  You need to ask a question - what you have given us is a project, not a question.  We will not do projects for you.

Comment: Btw, you need to say what is going to be inserting the email in the table, your app or another one.  If the latter, you may need to read up on triggers in MySql.

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what database you are using.  Using triggers you could probably have the database do this by itself without needing a delphi application at all.  See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10755518/327083

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email from MySQL 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1)

Answer (score 2):

Don't *poll* the DB for changes!

You will need a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) 
`ON INSERT` and probably some kind of [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) function.

If you don't want to write your own UDF, try to look at http://www.mysqludf.org/ in the "sys" repository. You will be able to "invoke shell commands" from MySQL. Please think of the security implication if you do that!

Comment: I tried to correct "pool" to "poll" but SO won't accept a change of less that 6 characters (!).

Comment: @MartynA Thank you Martyn. This is fixed now ;)

Answer (score 1):

With your query (Tquery,myquery, uniquery.. which you use) you can set a action using fields editor, Choose the field and set its onchange property to your mail function.In your function check the status of the message that you insert.If bool is true send the message and update status.

If you have much more data you can append the message info in clientdata or memdata and end of query you can send them.