# How can I receive an e-mail when my MySQL table is updated?

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

Hi I was wondering if there was a way in MySQL to automatically send an e-mail to myself whenever there is a row added to a MySQL table?

Comment: I am not sure if MYSQL server has that capability , if it does even I would love to know it. But if you are using your CGI then you can always tell it to mail u an update after every insert operation.

Comment: @hallaji, MySQL *is* a server side language.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to achieve this would be using a trigger and a cron.  Create a 'notification queue' table and populate that with a trigger when a row is inserted in the desired table.

eg.

```
CREATE TABLE `notification_queue` (
  `notification_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sent` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`)
);
```

Then define a simple trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t_notification_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON [table_being_inserted]
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO `notification_queue` (`sent`) VALUES (0);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

From that point, all you need to do is make a crontab run on the server (say every minute) which selects from the `notification` table where `sent = 0`, send the notification and set `sent = 1`

As far as I know, that's the best way to get that information out of the DB without reading the bin logs.

If you need an example of the script to run with cron:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_USER=''
DB_PASS=''
DB_NAME=''

ID=`mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -Bse "SELECT notification_id FROM notification_queue WHERE sent=0 LIMIT 1;"`

if [[ ! -z $ID ]] 
then
    # SEND MAIL HERE
    RESULT=`mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -Bse "UPDATE notification_queue SET sent=1 WHERE notification_id = $ID;"`
    echo "Sent"
fi
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any clarification on this.  I know there's a lot to the answer!

Comment: I'm working on this now. I've created the table. However, when I create the **TRIGGER**, I get the following error...  <br/>
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5**  <br/>

...and this is my `Line 5'...  <br/>

**`INSERT INTO `notification_queue` VALUES ();`**  <br/>

Here's a screenshot - [Print Screen](http://prntscr.com/4878kh)  <br/>
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry about the line breaks... I'm working on this now. I've created the table. However, when I create the **TRIGGER**, I get the following error...  
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5**  

...and this is my `Line 5'...  

**`INSERT INTO `notification_queue` VALUES ();`**  

Here's a screenshot - [Print Screen](http://prntscr.com/4878kh)  

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @webfrogs I don't know if you ever got an answer to your question a few months ago but for the benefit of anyone else reading this, your error is because you didn't define the delimiter as $$ at the outset, meaning the default delimiter (semicolon) was in play, and your CREATE TRIGGER ended abruptly on line 5.

Comment: @Sam_Butler - nice spotting on that, not sure why I didn't notice that earlier but I've updated the example to reflect the change of delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `lastInsertedId` and if it's not zero send e-mail.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data','root','');

function insertData(){
    global $db;
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO `albums`(`Artist`, `Album`, `Year`, `Cover`, `Tracks`) VALUES ('Cosmic Gate','Start to feel','2014','cover.jpg',13)");
    $id = $db->lastInsertId();
    //returns last inserted ID
    return $id;
}

function selectData($id){
    global $db;
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE ID = $id");
    $results = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message = "Artist: ".$results[0]['Artist']."\n"."Album: ".$results[0]['Album'];
    return $message;
}
$email = insertData(); //get last inserted id
$EmailTo = "tentenpeter48@gmail.com";
$subject = 'mysql update';
$message = "New data inserted: \n".selectData($email);

if($email != 0){

    if(mail($EmailTo, $subject, $message)){
        echo 'success'; // for testing
    }
}
```

Comment: The application is not the db server. Someone can talk directly to the db server without talking to the application .