# Is there any way to send email from mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there is way to send email  when query executed manually in mysql server. Can  we do this in mysql trigger please advise me how do we get email when some query run in mysql

Comment: No, email functionality is not available in mysql. Use PHP or VC++ etc.

Comment: as far as I know : NO

Comment: Like everyone tells you. Don't even try to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1#387503

Answer (score 2):

please don't try to do that...

**MySQL is a pure Database it's not its business to send eMails.**
MySQL has no eMail functionality ether.

i'd recommend creating a new table and write a tuple in that table when the procedure is used.

Then poll that table (with a java application or so) and send the mail

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is just a database solution, where you can store and retrieve data. For query, you may use a server side scripting like PHP. Then using php, while doing a query, you may send emails. Set up email in your server to send to an id while mysql data is retrieved.