# How can MySQL send an email Alert if a procedure fails to execute?

Tags: mysql

I have created an event that will call a stored procedure every day. But If for any reason the procedure failed to execute I need to be notified so I can look into the problem.

If MySQL is not capable to send an email then what can I do to monitor the procedures?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean php... mysql can only store data, it cannot 'do stuff'

Comment: What are you using as front end?

Comment: @ManofSnow [really?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: According to MySQL: *MySQL does not support it because it introduces security risks. If you want to disregard those risks, you can write and compile a custom UDF into your copy of the MySQL server. It's sounder, though, to email from the application layer.*

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, that *cron* thing, and the schedule task you linked does not say you can send email through MySQL

Comment: Correct, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. I was just responding to the implication that the question was impossible without PHP, while you can perfectly well schedule an SP with just MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email from MySQL 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1)

Comment: @ManofSnow MySQL has had a built-in [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) since 5.1, so it can indeed "do stuff" without any external help... errors and warnings raised in scheduled events are written to the MySQL [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-log.html).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good note.  I've been in isolation (kidding) for the past 8 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply PUT all your code in a PHP Script and `cUrl` the link ( via cron ) . In the PHP script tou can use the logic to check weather the execution succeeded or failed. According to that you can use PHP's `mail()` function to send a mail .

Comment: Are you telling me there is way to schedule a page to be triggered in PHP? How can I do that?

Comment: @Mike on a *nix host, type `crontab -e` and enter `0 * * * * wget -s http://myurl/myresource` to 'hit' the page on the first minute of every hour. You can also invoke PHP directly if you don't want to expose the cron page to the outer world.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I am sorry, I don't know what you mean by nix host. I am have PHP installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. Can you please give me more information on how this works?

Comment: *nix is just shorthand for 'some Unix-like OS such as BSD, Linux or Solaris'. On Windows you can use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) for the same end, it's just harder to set up.

Comment: @Fawzan, We are talking about sending emails from the DB server, not the Web server.

Comment: If you want to solely depend on MySQL to do it, then there is no way you can do it.