# Best option to send email notification in advance for account expiration

Tags: php, mysql, email, notifications

I am working on a e-commerce kind of application which allows user to login register and also create a deal for him.
Every deal of the user has a expiry date attached to it.Now I store all the values in the DB table against the created deal.
I want to send the user a notification couple of days before his deal expires if he has not 
updated it.Now can I achieve it using the DB trigger in any way(write a script and return value from the DB trigger) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1) thread. 
I should run a cron job to check it for some time interval and send notification?

I am not sure FB or other sites do it for **birthday reminders** or other notification.Any details on the same would be helpful to go ahead.

Thank you

Comment: I guess `CRON` is just fine in your case.

Comment: So will it run every few hours and check for the dates and then send emails?

Comment: Depends on you, but I guess you can run every day for that date & check the coupons which are getting expiry in 2 or 3 days & send emails to them. Also make sure you don't send email again & again if already sent to that user about expiration.

Comment: Thank you.I believe services online do it the same way! :) Trying to understand the best possible way!